# Fixing text position in an animation

Tags: graphics, animation

Following I have a simple animation with a variable displayed inside the plot. The significant digits of the variable changes as you run the animation which results in a smaller jitter on the text's initial position. It might be small but I find it very distracting when the animation is saved as a video.

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[a*t], {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, Epilog -> Text[Style[Row@{"a value = ", a}, Bold, Blue, 15], {1, 1.5}]], {a, 0, 10, 0.1}]
```

Is there a way to get rid of the jitter in the text display. I believe by forcing the initial position of the text to be a fixed value we should be able to get rid of the jitter, but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[a*t], {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
  Epilog -> Text[Style[Row[{"a value =", 
       Pane[a, Alignment -> Right, ImageSize -> {50, Automatic}], 
       "  some more text"}], Bold, Blue, 15], {0.8, 1.5}]], {a, 0, 11,  0.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Simpler way to fix this: `Row[{"a value = ", a}, ImageSize -> 100]`

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you could fix the left-hand end of the text position, something like this:

```
Animate[Plot[Sin[a*t], {t, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> {0, 2},Epilog->Text[Style[Row@{"a value = ", a}, Bold, Blue, 15], {0.8, 1.5}, {-1,
  0}]], {a, 0, 10, 0.1}]
```

Comment: that works, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Another approach would be to use `NumberForm[a, {2,1}]` rather than `a` as the third component of the `Row`.

Comment: @JackLaVigne it will still jitter when changing to 10.0 from 9.9

Comment: @BlacKow You are right. I missed the 10. Using `NumberPadding` perfectly aligns numbers when I place them in a column (`NumberForm[a, {3, 1}, NumberPadding -> {" ", "0"}]`) but when I place it in the `Animate` the 10 jitters. I am sticking with **demm**'s solution.